# IIS 8.0 500.19 error on only the first request

Tags: iis, 500-error, windows-8, iis-8

I am running IIS 8.0 locally on my machine for testing purposes. I have installed PHP through the web platform installer and everything is working correctly. The only issue I'm running into is the first request that's sent after the web server has started generates a 500.19 error. After the first initial request that generates the error everything works perfectly fine until the web server is shut down and started up again (or until my machine gets restarted). Here is a rundown of the error:

```
Module             IIS Web Core
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler            Not yet determined
Error Code         0x80070005
Config Error       Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
Config File        \\?\C:\Users\Aaron\Programming\aaronjwood\web.config

Requested URL      http://dev:80/aaronjwood
Physical Path      C:\Users\Aaron\Programming\aaronjwood
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User         Not yet determined
```

I'm not using any kind of web.config file since all of the code I'm working on is either written in PHP or Perl. Is this because it's looking for a web.config file but can't find one? Is there a way to tell IIS not to look for one? I am much more experienced with Apache so this error is new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. It was a silly mistake on my part. I didn't have the appropriate permissions on the directory. I needed to add the IIS_IUSRS group to the directory; I incorrectly had the IUSR user which allowed everything to work but not without throwing that initial error first.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the folder that contains your web.config file. if that is shared on the network and remove the sharing. Doing this resolved the issue for me .